# Regex to match all parenthetical content, so long as a certain pattern is present somewhere in the parenthetical content

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to write a regular expression (using grep to execute it) that will return to me all occurrences of parenthetical content so long as a particular search pattern is present within that content. For example, I have the following text

> (McSweeney 2010)(Harpers October 2008)(McSweeney 2011)(Some Author, McSweeney, Some Other Author, 1995)

and I want to return all of the parenthetical content which contains "McSweeney" somewhere inside, so

> (McSweeney 2010)
>
> (McSweeney 2011)
>
> (Some Author, McSweeney, Some Other Author, 1995)

Is this possible in a single regular expression? I have been able to get all parenthetical content using

```
\((.*)\)
```

but it breaks down when I try to introduce words into the pattern.

Comment: What does `parenthetical` content mean ?  What would match `(Some Author, (McSweeney (Joe), Some Other Author, 1995)` "(McSweeney (Joe)" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -oE '\([^)]*McSweeney[^)]*\)' file
```

Output:

```
(McSweeney 2010)
(McSweeney 2011)
(Some Author, McSweeney, Some Other Author, 1995)
```

or with a string:

```
string="McSweeney"
grep -oE '\([^)]*'"$string"'[^)]*\)' file
```